# xaml parser is not detecting my converter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Like many others the xaml parser has decided not to detect my IvalueConverter object. First the converter:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Data;
namespace Chess_Piece_Viewer.Helpers
{
public class DebugConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public Object Convert(Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {

        //set a breakpoint here
        return value;
    }

    public Object ConvertBack(Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {

        //set a breakpoint here
        return value;
    }

}
```

}

Now the View (please note the DebugConverter object is underlined in Visual Studio because the parser cannot detect it which is my problem:

```
         <UserControl x:Class="Chess_Piece_Viewer.Views.ChessBoardView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:diagnostics="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
         xmlns:Helpers ="clr-namespace:CanvasViewTest.Helpers;assembly=CanvasViewTest"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         MinHeight="80" MinWidth="80"
         d:DesignHeight="160" d:DesignWidth="160">
        <UserControl.Resources>
        <Helpers:DebugConverter x:Name="DebugConverter"/>


</UserControl.Resources>
<Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.BoardBorderBrush, diagnostics:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" BorderThickness="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.BoardBorderThickness}" >
    <UniformGrid Rows="8" Columns="8" x:Name="Board">
    <Canvas>
            <Rectangle x:Name="a1" Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareBorder, diagnostics:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareColor}"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[0]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareBorder}">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareColor}"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[1]}"/>
        </Canvas>

        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[2]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[3]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[4]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[5]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[6]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[7]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[8]}"/>
        </Canvas>

        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[9]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[10]}"/>
        </Canvas>

        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[11]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[12]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[13]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[14]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[15]}"/>
        </Canvas>

        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[16]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[17]}"/>
        </Canvas>

        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[18]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[19]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[20]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[21]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[22]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[23]}"/>
        </Canvas>


        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[24]}"/>
        </Canvas>

        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[25]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[26]}"/>
        </Canvas>

        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[27]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[28]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[29]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[30]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[31]}"/>
        </Canvas>




        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[32]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[33]}"/>
        </Canvas>

        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[34]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[35]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[36]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[37]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[38]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[39]}"/>
        </Canvas>



        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[40]}"/>
        </Canvas>

        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[41]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[42]}"/>
        </Canvas>

        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[43]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[44]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[45]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[46]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[47]}"/>
        </Canvas>


        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[48]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[49]}"/>
        </Canvas>

        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[50]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[51]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[52]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[53]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[54]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[55]}"/>
        </Canvas>


        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[56]}"/>
        </Canvas>

        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[57]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[58]}"/>
        </Canvas>

        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[59]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[60]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[61]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.LightSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[62]}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[63]}"/>
        </Canvas>

    </UniformGrid>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have included `clr-namespace:CanvasViewTest.Helpers` instead of `Chess_Piece_Viewer.Helpers` namespace in your xaml

Comment: Thank you; so obvious but I kept overlooking it; I forgot I had to import the canvasview project to fix an earlier bug :)

Comment: You also need to set your converter in XAML x:key attribute instead x:name