# VS not detecting converter function in namespace

Tags: c#, xaml

Im using VS2013 and building a Windows Store App. The parser is not detecting the species_to_chart_itemsource_converter function. Specific error:

> The name '...' does not exist in namespace '...'

I have even tried using clr-namespace:Sustenance_V_1._0 but in vain. I also tried defining new namespaces in new .cs files but nothing seems to work. I have already referred the question : [xaml parser is not detecting my converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18555073/xaml-parser-is-not-detecting-my-converter)

Please help.

PS:I have defined a class species in MainPage itself but have not shown it here.

This is my MainPage.xaml.cs file:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
    using Windows.Foundation;
    using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes;
    using WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;


    // The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234238

    namespace Sustenance_V_1._0
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
        /// </summary>
        public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
        {


            //===========Converters==========//
            public class species_to_chart_itemsource_converter : IValueConverter
            {
                public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
                {
                    var sp = parameter as species;
                    List<Population> data = new List<Population>();
                    data.Add(new Population() { Name = "Healthy", Amount = sp.healthy });
                    data.Add(new Population() { Name = "Healthy", Amount = sp.sick });
                    return data;

                }

                public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            public MainPage()
            {
                this.InitializeComponent();

                add_species(all_species);
                link_members(all_species);
                LoadChartContents(all_species);
            }

            void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
            }
       }
   }
```

This is the top of MainPage.xaml file:

```
<Page
    xmlns:Charting="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Sustenance_V_1._0"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:DataVisualization="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization" xmlns:Controls="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls" x:Name="page"

    xmlns:l="clr-namespace:Sustenance_V_1._0"

    x:Class="Sustenance_V_1._0.MainPage"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Image">
            <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Uniform"/>
        </Style>
        <local:species_to_chart_itemsource_converter x:Key="chart_converter"/>

    </Page.Resources>
```

Comment: Having periods in your namespace is not good practice. Probably won't help but you should probably rename it to `Sustenance_V_1_0` (or remove the version number altogether)

Comment: @DavidG Unless those periods signify a difference in major function. (`System.Threading` vs `System.Text`)

Comment: @DavidG, I tried that also. Doesnt help.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it set up right now, its trying to find `species_to_chart_itemsource_converter` in the `Sustenance_V_1._0` namespace, but its not there. You have it hidden inside the `MainPage` class. So either you need to prefix it with `MainPage.species_to_chart_itemsource_converter` or move the converter outside of the `MainPage` class (and preferably into its own file).

```
namespace Sustenance_V_1._0
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            add_species(all_species);
            link_members(all_species);
            LoadChartContents(all_species);
        }

        void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }

    //This could be in a different file, but I placed it outside the class here just to illustrate.

    //===========Converters==========//
    public class species_to_chart_itemsource_converter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var sp = parameter as species;
            List<Population> data = new List<Population>();
            data.Add(new Population() { Name = "Healthy", Amount = sp.healthy });
            data.Add(new Population() { Name = "Healthy", Amount = sp.sick });
            return data;

        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it.. none of the them work for me
MainPage... error: nesting not allowed
Placing it outside MainPage class does not resolve the issue. same error

Comment: Can you provide the exact error? The "nesting" error is not related to the original error.

Comment: I used: <local:MainPage.species_to_chart_itemsource_converter x:Key="chart_converter"/>

and got 3 errors- 
Error 1 Nested properties are not supported: MainPage.species_to_chart_itemsource_converter.

Error 2 The attachable property 'species_to_chart_itemsource_converter' was not found in type 'MainPage'. 

Error 3 'Unexpected 'EMPTYPROPERTYELEMENT' in parse rule 'NonemptyPropertyElement ::= . PROPERTYELEMENT Content? ENDTAG.'.' Line number '12' and line position '10'.

Comment: Move `species_to_char_itemsource_converter` outside of `MainPage`, but inside of the `Sustenance_V_1._0` namespace.  Then reference in the xaml with `<local:species_to_chart_itemsource_converter x:Key="chart_converter"/>`

Comment: @CurtisHx , VS is still unable to find class in the namespace.
Error: "The name ' ' does not exist in namespace ' ' "
 :/